# Using area display template from root project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas, viewengine

I have an area in my mvc project and this  area has some display templates. If I use @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Image) I want to use the display template from my are for the Image. How can I configure my view engine so it also looks inside my area for the specific partial view?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your view at `Areas/AreaName/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MyImage.cshtml`

Comment: That's where I have my templates but it does not use it, I need to put it in ~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Image.cshtml

Comment: What is the type of Model.Image?

Comment: the type is SomeNameSpace.Image, I don't know if the problem is that my AreaName is Dashboard but the area directory name is /Areas/MyApp.UI

Comment: Is it not possible or what am I missing?